# Switch from VB to C# in Workflow Designer

Tags: visual-studio, xaml, workflow-foundation-4, workflow-activity

I'm creating an Activity Library in Visual Studio 11 Beta (although I've repeated all my steps in VS2010 with the same result), targeting the .NET 4.0 framework.

As I started entering arguments via the Workflow Designer, I noticed the "*Enter a VB Expression*" message in the Default Value box.  I'm not sure how to change the language context from VB to C#.

To create the project, I followed these steps:

1. Go to **File**> **New** and select **Project...**
2. In the **Installed**> **Templates** section of the New Project dialog window, select **Visual C#**> **Workflow**> **Activity Library**
3. Name the project, as usual, and click **OK**

And that's basically it.  I noticed then that the default `Activity1.xaml` file was expecting VB in the default values fields.  I deleted it and then followed these steps to create a new Activity:

1. Right-click on the project and select **Add**> **New Item...**
2. In the Add New Item dialog window, navigate to **Installed**> **Visual C# Items**> **Workflow**> **Activity**
3. Name the Activity and click OK

It was the same result, the Default Value fields are expecting a VB expression.

When I look at the XAML code, I can clearly see the `Microsoft.VisualBasic.Activities` namespace listed and a `VisualBasic.Settings` element, but I'm not sure what to do to change it; everytime I try, I just end up screwing things up.  Here's the XAML code being generated:

```
<Activity mc:Ignorable="sads sap" x:Class="THINKImport.CustomerAddOrderAdd"
 xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/netfx/2009/xaml/activities"
 xmlns:local="clr-namespace:THINKImport.THINKWebReference"
 xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
 xmlns:mva="clr-namespace:Microsoft.VisualBasic.Activities;assembly=System.Activities"
 xmlns:s="clr-namespace:System;assembly=System.Core"
 xmlns:s1="clr-namespace:System;assembly=System"
 xmlns:s2="clr-namespace:System;assembly=System.ServiceModel"
 xmlns:s3="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
 xmlns:sads="http://schemas.microsoft.com/netfx/2010/xaml/activities/debugger"
 xmlns:sap="http://schemas.microsoft.com/netfx/2009/xaml/activities/presentation"
 xmlns:t="clr-namespace:THINKImport"
 xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
<x:Members>
    <x:Property Name="user_login_data" Type="InArgument(local:user_login_data)" />
    <!--Removed the other properties for brevity-->
  </x:Members>
  <sap:VirtualizedContainerService.HintSize>440,440</sap:VirtualizedContainerService.HintSize>
  <mva:VisualBasic.Settings>Assembly references and imported namespaces for internal implementation</mva:VisualBasic.Settings>
</Activity>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> ***C# Expressions***
>
> Previously, all expressions in workflows can only be written in Visual
>   Basic. In **.NET Framework 4.5** RC, Visual Basic expressions are only
>   used for projects created using Visual Basic. Visual C# projects now
>   use C# for expressions. A fully functional C# expression editor is
>   provided which capabilities such as grammar highlighting and
>   intellisense. C# workflow projects created in previous versions that
>   use Visual Basic expressions will continue to work.
>
> As of Beta 1, C# expressions are validated at design-time. Errors in
>   C# expressions will be marked with a red wavy underline.

More: [What's New in Windows Workflow Foundation in .NET 4.5](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh305677%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Answer (score 6):

I was able to figure out the issue.

First, though, I was able to discover the root cause [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev11.query?appId=Dev11IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k%28System.Activities.Presentation.View.ExpressionTextBox.UI%29;k%28TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework,Version%3Dv4.0%29&rd=true).  In a nutshell, it says VB.NET must be used in the Expression Editor even if the program is in C#.

So, I was kinda bummed about that, but I decided to take another crack at the XAML code because, in working through the WF tutorials, there was most definitely an activity I was working on in the designer that would accept Expressions in C#.  I opened up that project and went through the XAML code.

It's then that I noticed this line:

```
<sap2010:ExpressionActivityEditor.ExpressionActivityEditor>C#</sap2010:ExpressionActivityEditor.ExpressionActivityEditor>
```

I searched the MSDN library and found the [documentation for the ExpressionActivityEditor class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh135717%28v=vs.110%29).  As best as I can tell, this is new to .NET 4.5.  In my particular case, there isn't any reason I can't target .NET 4.5 in my project, so I changed it.  Once the solution reopened, right away, all the Expression Editor text fields and boxes would accept C#.  In order to "start fresh", I deleted the activity file I had been working on and created a new one.  If anyone's interested, here's that generated XAML code:

```
<Activity mc:Ignorable="sap sap2010 sads" x:Class="THINKImport.CustomerAddOrderAdd"
      xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/netfx/2009/xaml/activities"
      xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
      xmlns:sads="http://schemas.microsoft.com/netfx/2010/xaml/activities/debugger"
      xmlns:sap="http://schemas.microsoft.com/netfx/2009/xaml/activities/presentation"
      xmlns:sap2010="http://schemas.microsoft.com/netfx/2010/xaml/activities/presentation"
      xmlns:sco="clr-namespace:System.Collections.ObjectModel;assembly=mscorlib"
      xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
      xmlns:THINKWebReference="clr-namespace:THINKImport.THINKWebReference">
  <x:Members>
  <x:Property Name="user_login_data" Type="InArgument(THINKWebReference:user_login_data)">
    <x:Property.Attributes>
      <RequiredArgumentAttribute />
        </x:Property.Attributes>
    </x:Property>
    <x:Property Name="customer_data" Type="InArgument(THINKWebReference:customer_data)" />
    <!--Remainder of Properties removed for brevity-->
  </x:Members>
  <sap2010:ExpressionActivityEditor.ExpressionActivityEditor>C#</sap2010:ExpressionActivityEditor.ExpressionActivityEditor>
  <TextExpression.NamespacesForImplementation>
    <sco:Collection x:TypeArguments="x:String">
      <x:String>System</x:String>
      <x:String>System.Collections.Generic</x:String>
      <x:String>System.Data</x:String>
      <x:String>System.Linq</x:String>
      <x:String>System.Text</x:String>
    </sco:Collection>
  </TextExpression.NamespacesForImplementation>
  <TextExpression.ReferencesForImplementation>
    <sco:Collection x:TypeArguments="AssemblyReference">
      <AssemblyReference>mscorlib</AssemblyReference>
      <AssemblyReference>System</AssemblyReference>
      <AssemblyReference>System.Core</AssemblyReference>
      <AssemblyReference>System.Data</AssemblyReference>
      <AssemblyReference>System.ServiceModel</AssemblyReference>
      <AssemblyReference>System.Xml</AssemblyReference>
    </sco:Collection>
  </TextExpression.ReferencesForImplementation>
  <sap2010:WorkflowViewState.IdRef>
    THINKImport.CustomerAddOrderAdd_1
  </sap2010:WorkflowViewState.IdRef>
  <sap2010:WorkflowViewState.ViewStateManager>
    <sap2010:ViewStateManager>
      <sap2010:ViewStateData Id="THINKImport.CustomerAddOrderAdd_1" sap:VirtualizedContainerService.HintSize="440,440" />
    </sap2010:ViewStateManager>
  </sap2010:WorkflowViewState.ViewStateManager>
</Activity>
```

So, quite a bit different (to me, anyways) but I can use C# now, so I'm happy.